# Overpass API returns incomplete polygon ERROR with responseformat "geojson"

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geojson, overpass-api

I am trying to run an Overpass query from Python with the help of [this Overpass plugin](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper). I tested the request, see here: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/19YC

However, my python code...

```
import overpass
from geojson import dump

api = overpass.API()
query = 'nwr["landuse"="forest"](47.434604,11.730938,47.450049,11.74238);'
result = api.get(query, responseformat="geojson") 

with open('forest.geojson', 'w') as f:
    dump(result, f)
```

... results in this error:

> UnknownOverpassError: Received corrupt data from Overpass (incomplete polygon).

Other response formats like json, xml do not produce errors but don't give me the desired output format. I was not successful reformatting JSON output to GeoJSON with plugins **osm2geojson** or **osmtogeojson** either.

What can be done to achieve a straight forward request and a GeoJSON file in the end?

Comment: https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/issues/135 might help. Library is currently unmaintained, you're on your own here.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. Unfortunately, the patch produces other errors. Think I will write my own simple batchfile for querying the overpass api.